How can I efficiently parse a complex JSON object with dynamic keys in Python for managing shipping container data?
I'm working on a project for a shipping container company where we need to process data from an external API that provides information about container shipments. The JSON data structure returned by the API is highly dynamic, with certain keys and nested objects that can change depending on the type of shipment or the data being provided.
{
    "container_id": "ABC123",
    "status": "In Transit",
    "location": {
        "latitude": "40.7128",
        "longitude": "-74.0060",
        "city": "New York"
    },
    "cargo": {
        "type": "Electronics",
        "weight": "500kg"
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "event_type": "Departure",
            "timestamp": "2024-08-29T08:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "event_type": "Customs Clearance",
            "timestamp": "2024-08-30T12:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}

In another response, the structure might vary, with some keys missing or new ones added:
{
    "container_id": "DEF456",
    "status": "Delivered",
    "location": {
        "city": "Los Angeles"
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "event_type": "Arrival",
            "timestamp": "2024-08-31T14:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}

I need a Pythonic way to handle this kind of dynamic JSON data efficiently. Specifically, I'm looking for strategies to:

Safely access deeply nested keys without causing errors if they don't exist.
Iterate over the JSON to extract specific information related to shipping status, location, and events, regardless of the structure's variability.
Ensure that the code remains readable and performant, especially when processing large amounts of shipment data.

What are some best practices or libraries that can help manage this type of complex and dynamic JSON parsing in Python, particularly in the context of a shipping or logistics company?
For example the project is https://www.eliteshippingcontainers.us/

There's module literally called json in Python that can parse it to Python objects with one method.

You can convert json to dictionary using d=json.loads(jsonString) and then use d.get with a default value without causing errors.

I would use e.g. Pydantic when ingesting the data to get a structure of well-typed Python objects out of it.

@matszwecja Their question is about processing the parsed objects, not about parsing the JSON.

In whichever way you parse it or access it or convert it to classes as suggested below, you’ll simply be using a lot of conditional statement somewhere. If some piece of information exists, use it, otherwise don’t. Rinse, repeat for all optional pieces of data which may exist. Whether you can simplify that into certain patterns (e.g. either A, B and C exist together or not at all) and maybe into certain classes from there, we can’t tell you and you’ll need to read up on that in the API documentation.

I would use Pydantic for strongly typed validated models (the data model here is derived using QuickType, but you could do it by hand or from a spec you have), so instead of working with dicts, you'd work with actual Python objects, and things will break during parsing, not when you try to work with the data.
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

import pydantic

examples = [
    # (from OP's question, elided here)
]


class Cargo(pydantic.BaseModel):
    type: str
    weight: str


class Event(pydantic.BaseModel):
    event_type: str
    timestamp: datetime


class Location(pydantic.BaseModel):
    city: str
    latitude: Optional[str] = None
    longitude: Optional[str] = None


class ShippingContainer(pydantic.BaseModel):
    container_id: str
    status: str
    location: Location
    events: list[Event]
    cargo: Cargo | None = None


for example in examples:
    cont = ShippingContainer.model_validate(example)
    print(cont)

prints out
container_id='ABC123' status='In Transit' location=Location(city='New York', latitude='40.7128', longitude='-74.0060') events=[Event(event_type='Departure', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 29, 8, 0, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC))), Event(event_type='Customs Clearance', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 30, 12, 0, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)))] cargo=Cargo(type='Electronics', weight='500kg')

container_id='DEF456' status='Delivered' location=Location(city='Los Angeles', latitude=None, longitude=None) events=[Event(event_type='Arrival', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 31, 14, 0, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)))] cargo=None

and you could access those objects with e.g. cont.location.city or for ev in cont.events: print(ev.timestamp.year).

You can use Python's dict.get() method to safely access deeply nested keys.
Example:
data1 = {
    "container_id": "ABC123",
    "location": {
        "latitude": "40.7128",
        "longitude": "-74.0060",
        "city": "New York"
    }
}

data2 = {
    "container_id": "DEF456",
    "location": {
        "city": "Los Angeles"
    }
}

print("Data 1:")
latitude = data1.get('location', {}).get('latitude')
print("Latitude: " + latitude) if latitude else print('Latitude not found')

print("Data 2:")
longitude = data2.get('location', {}).get('longitude')
print(longitude) if longitude else print('Longitude not found')


Output:
Data 1:
Latitude: 40.7128
Data 2:
Longitude not found

